# How to create Circle shape button using Monotouch for Ipad?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

How to create Circle shape button using Monotouch for iOS?

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom button:

```
UIButton myButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
```

Assign a background image, with the shape you want:

```
myButton.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile("circle.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/193/Creating-transparent-rounded-buttons-in-MonoTouch/ to draw one using a standard UIButton.